# Trimming a textfile

Tags: bash, variables, sed

i want to trim a textfile and delete all lines from line n to the end of the file. I tried to use sed for that. The sed command for n=26 should look like that:

```
sed -i '26,$d' /path/to/textfile
```

So in my textfile i don't know n beforehand, but i know that there is a unique text in that line. So i tried it that way:

```
myvar=`grep -n 'unique text' /path/to/textfile | awk -F":" '{print $1 }'`
sed -i "${myvar}"',$d' /path/to/textfile
```

That works and deletes all wanted lines but it throws the error message:

```
sed: -e expression # 1, character 1: unknown command: »,«
```

So i tried changing my command to:

```
myvar=`grep -n 'unique text' /path/to/textfile | awk -F":" '{print $1 }'`
sed -i "${myvar},$d" /path/to/textfile
```

With that i get the same error message but it doesn't delete the lines.
I tried some variations with ' and " and how to put the variable in there, but it never works as wanted. Does someone knows what i do wrong?

I would appreciate other methods for trimming the textfile as long as i can do it in a bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the fixed line number with a regular expression matching the line to start at.

```
sed -i '/unique text/,$d' /path/to/textfile
```

You can also use `ed` to edit the file, rather than rely on a non-standard `sed` extension.

```
printf '/unique text/,$d\nwq\n' | ed /path/to/textfile
```

Comment: There is a typo in both commands, it is $d not d$...

But they are working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Hypercorrection; I kept wanting to read that as a parameter expansion when I *knew* it wasn't, so I apparently typed it so that it couldn't be one :)